# Logic behind :hover selector in dropdown menus

Tags: css, hover

Might be a small thing, but I am struggling to find out how the hover selector works logically in dropdown menus.
Here's the entire code in question: https://jsfiddle.net/5dcd9zLh/

```
.droplist {
   display:none; 
}

li:hover > .droplist {
   display: block;
}
```

Here's my understanding of the current code. 
 
Step 1: li is being hovered over 
Step 2: Select all child elements .droplist 
Step 3: Apply styling display:block to .droplist 

Wouldn't that mean the moment I start to hover my cursor from li over to droplist, the styling would revert back to display:none? Why is it that .droplist maintains its display:block property when li is no longer being hovered over?

Answer (score 1):

Because .droplist is child of li tag. Thus, when you hover to .droplist, this still known as you hover on li tag.

The :hover selector can be known is: "When mouse over me or all of my childs"

Hope this will help you understand this!